# Arduino practice with a DHT 11 temp/humid sensor but having an issue

Tags: arduino, lcd, arduino-c++

I am currently sending temperature data from the sensor to an lcd 16x2 display I am able to display the temperature but it keeps alternating from the temperature to -999 it displays the data like this too in the Serial monitor when I print it their too. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here is my sloppy code sorry it's not properly noted but I'm still grasping the basics.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <dht.h>

dht DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 12

LiquidCrystal lcd(13 ,11,10,9,8,7,6 ,5 , 4, 3 );

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
 int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 lcd.print("Temperature =");
 lcd.setCursor(0,2);
 lcd.print(DHT.temperature);
 delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Removed DHT tag since it is for distributed hash tables, not temperature sensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, just as an advice, place the `lcd.begin()` function in the setup function, and not in the loop, because the lcd must be initialized just one time.

Then, reading the datasheet of the DHT11 sensor I found that the minimum time between two sensor readings should be at least 2 seconds, so probably changing `delay(1000)` to `delay(2000)` should do the job.

Comment: Thank you the error is gone and it's displaying the correct numbers. I never knew their was that large of a gap in sensor readings and this has shown me to read the data sheets for sensors in the future.